# Which Framework able to scan text file

Tags: java, text, full-text-search, text-files

I would like to extract data from a text file where there’s no specific format.

Is there a framework or technology out there that can do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with machine-learning or AI (tags removed). Can I kindly ask you to only use the relevant tags? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. To be honest I have no idea which tags I have to use for this, as you can see from my question that I don’t know which technology to use. Would you be able to suggest which tags are appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language do you want to use? Add this as a tag. The rest of your tags is fine and makes sense.

Comment: Thanks  I added the language.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your endeavour. 